# magical isosceles triangle and 13/15 ratio

Tags: geometry, triangles, square-numbers

It seems eerily magical that $\dfrac {13}{15}$ corresponds within $99.926$ percent accuracy to the height of an isosceles triangle 
the height of isosceles $= \sqrt {.75} = 0.8660254...$ and 
$\dfrac {13}{15}=0.866666...$

Please explain to me the statistical reason for which this could be a simple coincidence?
This is how close $\sqrt{.75}$ is to $\dfrac {13}{15}$:

it's only different by a factor of $0.000739918710263$

i.e.
 $7.399$ thousandths..

If this post is not suitable for this forum, please rewrite it so it is. Thanks.

Comment: Please improve the language clarity of the question or else it will get repeatedly down-voted.

Comment: Okay thanks apurv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{4}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{675}{900}}$ while $\dfrac{13}{15} = \sqrt{\dfrac{676}{900}}$.

So the absolute difference between their squares is $\dfrac{1}{900}$. This is small (and smaller still after taking the square roots) but not particularly special.

Answer (score 1):

I think this coincidence is one of many that can be attributed to the "[*strong law of small numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers)".  Although it is tempting to assume that there is some sort of mystical connection there after finding such a remarkable coincidence, it is doubtful that there is one, since these coincidences occur very often and, from a statistical standpoint, inevitably.

One of my favorite numerical coincidences is that $e^\pi - \pi$ is very close to $20$. As for some more, here's a relevant [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/1047/) which lists a bunch, some of which seem surprisingly useful.

Comment: If anything then [this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/217/) should have been mentioned... :-)

Comment: Thankyou, there is also a wiki artical on mathematical coincidence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence